# appendTo does not work on ajaxForm in success:

Tags: jquery

I want to append quest1 to #adder, but just does not happen

```
$('#formnam').ajaxForm(function() { 

                var quest = $('#Text').attr('value');
        var quest1 = '<div>'+$('#Text').attr('value')+'</div>';

                  $.ajax({

            type: "post",
            url: "submit.php",
            data: "q="+quest,
            success: function() {


                   $('#Adder').html(quest1);

            }
        });
            });
```

It works if I use .text or .html, but I want appendTo.

Does not work on chrome, IE, ff

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.html()` does indeed overwrite the html content from `#Adder`. If you want to append new stuff, use `.append()` instead.

Ref.: [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: why not .appendTo..need to wait 8 mins to approve

Comment: @Jean: of course you can use `.appendTo()` too. But that only makes sense if the contents of `quest1` are `html markup`, a `dom node` or a `jQuery object`. Then it is even smarter to use `.appendTo()` because you keep the reference to the original node and can chain more methods you want to apply.

Comment: If I use .appendTo the #adder does not show up, nor the values are anywhere in it.  now thats funny

Comment: @Jean: how does your code look like with `appendTo()` ? You need to reverse the order of things, `.appendTo()` needs the target node. So this context it would look like `$(quest1)`.appendTo($('#Adder'));`

Answer (score 1):

use `append`, `appendto` appends to the parameter.
http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/